# how to edit default artisan command laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

when I run

> php artisan make:request "TestRequest"

it will create file like below :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TestRequest extends FormRequest // i want to change from extends 'Form Request' to extends 'MyCustomFormRequest'
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

so as you can see above is the default one, I wanted to change extends class from 'FormRequest' (this is default) to MyCustomFormRequest (this is my custom)

so how do I achieve when I run

> php artisan make:request "TestRequest"

, it will automatically extends 'MyCustomFormRequest' instead of 'FormRequest' ?

Comment: Just change FormRequest to MyCustomFormRequest and its namespaces?

Comment: To change the default artisan command behavior you need to work on laravel core. which I highly suggest **not to do** Instead make your own command and register them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First ,you need to create a new command

```
php artisan make:command CustomRequestMakeCommand
```

Copy all code from Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RequestMakeCommand to App\Console\Commands\CustomRequestMakeCommand ( Remember to change the class ,namespace,and name command also)

Secondly ,create a new sub at console folder name like "stubs/customrequest.stub" ,copy all code from request.stub (vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/stubs/request.stub) to the new one ,change the FromRequest to YourCustomFormRequest

```
class DummyClass extends CustomFormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Then you can use your custom command ,you can read more about this at 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan

Comment: thank you , successfully registering command by referring to https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#registering-commands